# How to fix glibc vulnerability CVE-2015-7547

Tags: security, update

https://www.debian.org/security/2016/dsa-3481

Do we need to wait for a RASPBIAN upgrade to be available here?

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/

I ran:
`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo reboot`
... but I don't think I saw any explicit `glibc` patch come through

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the Debian Security Tracker entry for this vulnerability](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2015-7547), updates for `glibc`/`eglibc`/`libc6` will fix this issue:

- wheezy: 2.13-38+deb7u10
- jessie: 2.19-18+deb8u3

These are available for Raspian as well. A simple

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

should secure your box.

To verify the version of your glibc, run

```
apt-cache show libc6 | grep -i "version:"
```